# Trying to create a character counter, but my button is not updating the while loop boolean to do so

Tags: java, swing

so I am trying to make a small java program to count the number of characters in a given string.
Right now, my code works in the console output, but it is not updating the text field I have created in a JFrame and I am unsure why. Can someone please explain this to me?

BTW: I have set "onPress" to true, so the button doesn't really have an effect right now, I'm just trying to test the functionality of the program before I implement button functionality.

Thank you :)! Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class characterCounterTwov2 extends JFrame {

static boolean onPress = true;

public characterCounterTwov2(){

    /*******************/
    /* Local Variables */
    /*******************/

    //creates a new Jframe to put our frame objets in
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    //creates a text field frame object
    JTextField txtField = new JTextField("Enter your text here", 25);
    //stores the string of the the jtextfield into a variable text
    String text = txtField.getText();

    //creates a text field that is uneditable with the word "characters"
    String charString = "Characters: ";
    JTextField charField = new JTextField(charString, 25);
    charField.setEditable(false);

    //integer to count the characters
    int charCounter = 0;

    //string that will be used in a text field to display the # of chars
    String charCount = Integer.toString(charCounter);

    //Text field that displays charCount
    JTextField charFieldTwo = new JTextField(charCount, 10);

    //calculate button
    JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    calcButton.addActionListener(new calcButtonFunc());

    /*******************/
    /*   Frame Setup   */
    /*******************/

    //sets the layout of the frame
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //add's elements to the frame
    frame.add(txtField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(charField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(charFieldTwo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(calcButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //begin while loop
    //infinite while loop
    System.out.println("Entering main while loop");
    while(true)
    {
        while(onPress == true)
        {
         System.out.println("text length is:" + charCount);
           for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
            {
             charCounter++;
             System.out.println("Number of characters:" + charCounter);
            }

            //charCount = Integer.toString(charCounter);
            onPress = false;        
        }
    }
}

static class calcButtonFunc implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
    {
        onPress = true;
    }
 }

public static void main(String[] args){
    new characterCounterTwov2();
    System.out.println("End of program. Should not get here");
    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~
**EDIT**

I was given a lot of helpful tips by Hovercraft Full of Eels, and cleaned up my code. I am still having a problem with calculating the character count on button press, and having it reflect in the GUI. I am thinking my bug lies within the line "text = txtField.getText();" inside my button listener class.

Here is my updated code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class characterCounterTwov4{
    //creates a new Jframe to put our frame objets in
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    //creates a text field frame object
    JTextField txtField = new JTextField(25);

    //stores the string of the the jtextfield into a variable text
    String text = txtField.getText();

    //creates a text field that is uneditable with the word "characters"
    String charString = "Characters: ";
    JTextField charField = new JTextField(charString, 25);

public characterCounterTwov4(){

    charField.setEditable(false);

    //integer to count the characters
    int charCounter = 0;

    //string that will be used in a text field to display the # of chars
    String charCount = Integer.toString(text.length());

    //Text field that displays charCount
    JTextField charFieldTwo = new JTextField(charCount, 10);        

    //calculate button
    JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    calcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
         {
            System.out.println("button pressed");

            //stores the string of the the jtextfield into a variable text
            text = txtField.getText();

            //string that will be used in a text field to display the # of chars
            String charCount = Integer.toString(text.length());

            //Text field that displays charCount
            JTextField charFieldTwo = new JTextField(charCount, 10);
         }
    });

    /*******************/
    /*   Frame Setup   */
    /*******************/

    //sets the layout of the frame
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //add's elements to the frame
    frame.add(txtField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(charField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(charFieldTwo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(calcButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new characterCounterTwov4();
    System.out.println("End of program. Should not get here");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not structured for correct Swing GUI event-driven programming but rather looks like a linear console program that is being shoe-horned into a GUI. Get rid of that while loop, get rid of that static boolean variable. Instead give your class a non-static (instance) int counter variable and a JTextField non-static variable and simply increment your counter in the actionPerformed method and display the results in the JTextField (or JLabel if you prefer).

So the actionPerformed could look something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEVent e) {
   counter++; // increment the counter variable
   charCount.setText("Count: " + counter); // display the results
}
```

and again, counter and charCount are non-static and are declared and initialized in the class, not inside of the constructor or any method.

---

**Edit**
Additional notes:

- Why does your class extend JFrame when you don't use it as a JFrame?
- In general, it's a good idea to start all Swing proggrams on the Swing **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread or **EDT**. This can be done by passing a Runnable with your start-up code in it to the SwingUtilities static method `invokeLater(...)`.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
     }
  });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
  // create and display your GUI from in here
  MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();

  JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
  mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  mainFrame.add(mainGui);
  mainFrame.pack();
  mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

**Edit 2**
Oops, I read your requirements wrong. You need to count the chars in a String, and so you will need another class instance JTextField, one to hold the user's String, get rid of the counter instance field since it no longer will be needed, and then in the actionPerformed method, simply get the String from the JTextField, get its length, and display the length in another JTextField or in a JLabel, again your choice.

---

**Edit 3**
Your code is now ***almost*** there!
Problems:

- The charFieldTwo variable is a non-final local variable. To be able to use it in your anonymous inner class, either make it final, and note that doing this won't harm its ability to work since it is a reference variable, not a primite,
- Or you could move its declaration out of the constructor, like you do the other variables.
- Once you've done this, it is easy to call `charFieldTwo.setText(charCount);` on it at the bottom of your ActionListener, and you're pretty much done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The reason I originally included a while loop, is that I want to be able to edit the text field, and recalculate the character length of the string by pressing the button.

Comment: @ddantas: which is exactly why you **don't** want a while loop. That will stomp all over your GUI's event thread, and it's not the way to do this. Simply have your JButton's ActionListener get the latest text from the JTextField, and have it update the output JLabel or JTextField.

Comment: Oh alright, I understand. Would that require me to make a static instance JTextField variable then? I'm thinking this is what my button's listener should do:

`static class calcButtonFunc implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event)
     {
      //onPress = true;

     //string that will be used in a text field to display the # of chars
  String charCount = Integer.toString(text.length);

  //Text field that displays charCount
  JTextField charFieldTwo = new JTextField(charCount, 10);
     }
  }`

Comment: `"Would that require me to make a static instance JTextField variable then?"` -- nope, that's the last thing that you want to do. As I have already stated in my answer, use non-static instance fields only. Also, please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25577580/edit).

Comment: @ddantas: also, don't use a static inner class, but rather a non-static inner class, or an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm pretty new to making posts on stack overflow.

As for your answer, I tried doing so, and I get the error "error: non-static variable text cannot be referenced from a static context"

Here is my updated code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/c5GHUDZ0

Comment: I just saw your post about anonymous inner class. I tried that, but it was saying that I need to declare my count variable as final, which I think is the opposite of what I want, since I want that number able to be updated.

Comment: @ddantas: that's because you've declared count, shoot you've done pretty much everything, including loading most of your program logic, inside of your constructor, and you can only access local variables in an anonymous class if their final. Again, I'm telling you don't do this -- don't make your most important variables local. Instead, your important variables should be instance variables declared in the class, not local variables. Please try my suggestions.

Comment: ok, I think I understand. So when I create the anonymous inner class, should I declare my local variables there?

By the way, thank you for answering all my questions.



Edit:
I think I misunderstood what you meant, but NOW I believe I get it. I was confused on the nomenclature of "local vs instance variables". Instance variables are variables declared OUTSIDE off the classes correct?

I'm somewhat new to Java

Comment: Nothing is allowed outside of classes. Are you confusing constructors with classes? Now I'm not trying to be rude (but I am blunt), but it sounds like you need to read or re-read some of your text to gain an understanding of this stuff, since it looks like you're doing a bit of guessing. The books won't lead you astray, and the study time won't be wasted. Otherwise, your best bet is to try, to experiment, to see what works and what doesn't. The more code you write, the better you'll become.

Comment: So I spent some time revamping my code with the things you suggested, and I think my code looks a lot nicer!

The only problem I am currently having is that my character count won't update still.

Do you mind taking a look at it and give me some pointers?
http://pastebin.com/RnzMn3VU

Comment: I believe my problem lies with line 41. I believe the getText() call is getting the text from the original txtField variable, which is empty.

Comment: @ddantas: edit your original question and post your new code as an addition to the bottom of the question. Don't delete your current question text or its code, so as not to invalidate answers, but add the new code to the bottom.